# How can I mount a partition on every reboot?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition

I have a partition mounted with `mount -t ext3 /dev/sda3 /foo`.

Each time I reboot, I need to remount.  How can I keep this mounted after every reboot?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to make an entry in `/etc/fstab` for the mount, something like:

```
/dev/sda3 /foo                       ext3    defaults        1 1
```

For more information see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: You may want to use `nofail` flag so that you'll able to normally boot your system when `/dev/sda3` is not able to mount for some reason.

Comment: To find out the file system type, run `file -s /dev/sda3`

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes, one may face critical issues due to `/etc/fstab` entries.  So, the alternative is crontab.

Just add below entry in root's crontab.

`$ sudo crontab -e`

`@reboot mount -t ext3 /dev/sda3 /foo`

Comment: Are you really suggesting to use an ugly hack instead of the proper way of doing it, which has been in use for *decades* and never actually caused those "critical issues" to anyone?!?

Comment: I faced this situation while working on cloud machine on AWS. There was some problem while mounting using /etc/fstab, and the system was halting boot process.  So, the system became useless as it was remote. So, i prefer safe boot (without specifying an entry in fstab) and then issue mount in crontab.

Comment: @Massimo actually "critical issues" do exist. Here's what a Google engineer says about mounting a certain cloud storage (like Amazon S3) FUSE filesystem via fstab at boot: _"let me urge you to not do this. Requests to GCS are not nearly as reliable as local disk, and you're likely to find yourself with a system that hangs on boot if anything goes wrong"_ ( [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/135#issuecomment-151009207) )

Comment: Not sure what to do instead though, but crontab and `@reboot` makes sense to me. Perhaps in combination with a fstab `noauto` row, or `mount` directly in the crontab.  — Anyway, upvoted from -3 to -2, because this answer is actually useful, in some rare cases. (And edit suggestoin: "sometimes" --> "in rare cases" :- )  )

Comment: This is what I did in my case: `@reboot echo '/opt/ed/mount-google-cloud-storage-backups-bucket.sh >> /opt/ed/cron.log 2>&1' | at now + 3 minutes`, works OK perhaps not for everyone, but for my use case.

Comment: What are the critical issue that would not permit entries into fstab, could you give an exemple of cases.

Comment: @Massimo i to had boot problems when added the mount. if the mount fails boot fails and you can not enter your machine!

Answer (score 0):

For OpenSuse, coming from Novell [Automatically mount a windows share at boot time with Linux](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7000932)

```
//winserver/share /mnt/winshare cifs gid=users,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,auto,username=john,password=johnpass 0 0
```

Please add single quotes if the folder names contains spaces:

```
'//winserver/share with spaces' '/mnt/winshare with spaces' cifs gid=users,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,auto,username=john,password=johnpass 0 0
```

Check the end of the article if you don't want to put passwords in fstab.